# Create Sessionless or Sessionful Channel

Tags: wcf

Can Anybody tell me in WCF how can I create a sessionful or sessionless Channel in SessionMode.Allowed. Which means allow both types of Conversation with WCF Service. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SessionMode` only describes contract of your Service but does not implement required behavior. `SessionMode.Allowed` tells everybody that service works fine with session and without session. Using or not using session is defined in binding.

Different kinds of bindings provides different set of features. Some features require/include session support.

You can use several bindings for the same contract and one binding will implement session when at the same time other binding will not.

For example code below creates sessionful Channel because WSHttpBinding implements message security.

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc");
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new 
                    ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(binding, address);
ICalculator channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Adding this line will make Channel sessionless:

```
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
```

Binding bellow is sessionless as well because `BasicHttpBinding` implements `SecurityMode.None` by default.

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/MathService/Ep1");
ChannelFactory<IMath> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMath>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
```

Security-based sessions are not the only type of session supported by WCF.
WCF supports 4 different types of sessions:

- Security-based sessions, in which both ends of communication have
  agreed upon a specific secure conversation.
- TCP/IP-based sessions to ensure that all messages are correlated by
  the connection at the socket level.
- The System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableSessionBindingElement
  element, which implements the WS-ReliableMessaging specification,
  provides support for reliable sessions
- The System.ServiceModel.NetMsmqBinding binding provides MSMQ datagram
  sessions.

Your service will be sessionfull if binding implements any of the features mentioned above.

See MSDN for more details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean the [SessionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.sessionmode.aspx) property on the [[ServiceContract]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx) attribute.
If this is the case, I think you're misunderstood on the concept of sessions in a contract. Whether a channel is sessionful or not depends on the binding which is used to create the channel. The `SessionMode` property is used for validation, during runtime, that the endpoint for that contract is using an appropriate binding.

For the three values of session mode:

- **Required**: that means that the binding used in the endpoint for the contract **must** support sessions. If a binding does not support session, then the client will throw when being used for the first time, or the service host will throw during Open
- **NotAllowed**: the opposite: if the binding used in the endpoint does support sessions, then the runtime will throw (while opening the service or the client)
- **Allowed**: the default value, the contract can be used for all bindings regardless of their support for sessions.

The remarks section of the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.sessionmode.aspx) for the property has more information about this property.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Good explaination. This is what I was looking for.